# Component is rendering props.children before parent logic is completed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to teach myself next.js and I'm struggle with some auth logic issues I'm having.

I have a page `protected/profile`, which I want to stop the user from accessing if they are not logged in. To check this, I'm retrieving some user data via getServerSideProps, and then I'm trying to pass the returned user data to the component, the component then passes that to a child element called `Protected`. Protected is what performs the logic to check whether the user is logged in, and if the user is logged in the profile page should be displayed by returning props.children.

If the user is not logged in they should be redirected to `/`

However it looks like the profile component is just rendering the profile page regardless and isn't waiting for the protected logic to complete. If I try to access the profile page while logged out, I get an error saying user.user_metadata can't be found, when really I should be getting redirected.

The console logs ends up being

```
Profile log
protected.tsx:7 Protected log
protected.tsx:17 Protected: Has user
```

```
const Profile = ({user} : {user: User}) => {
    console.log("Profile log");
    return (
        <Protected user={user}>
            <h1>This is Profile</h1>
            <h1>Hello, {user.user_metadata.full_name}!</h1>
            <p> Your email : {user.email}</p>
        </Protected>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({req}) => {
    const {user} = await supabaseClient.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req);
    return { props: {user: user}}
}

export default Profile;
```

```
export default function Protected(props: {user: User, children}){
    console.log("Protected log");
    if(!props.user){
        console.log("Protected: Null user");
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: "/",
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Protected: Has user");
    return props.children;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to log `user` object when logged out? Also, you can't return object (`redirect` and etc) from React component, this won't work even if your `user` logic is fine.

Comment: @Danila The redirect works completely fine otherwise, it's not the issue here

Comment: It can't possibly work, you returning object instead of JSX.

Comment: You copied wrongly from tutorial. You can return `redirect` object from `getServerSideProps` function, but not from React component.

Comment: @Danila Sorry yeah I'm forgetting I've changed the code from the original given in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, as I said in the comment, you can't return `redirect` object from React component, this won't work. If you want to use `redirect` object you need to return it from `getServerSideProps`. Or make some custom logic with `useRouter` or something like that.

Second, you should type `user` as optional, because it might not exist (according to your code):

```js
const Profile = ({user} : {user?: User}) => {
    console.log("Profile log");
    return (
        <Protected user={user}>
            <h1>This is Profile</h1>
            <h1>Hello, {user.user_metadata.full_name}!</h1>
            <p> Your email : {user.email}</p>
        </Protected>
    )
}
```

Now you will see Typescript error already, that you are trying to access properties from possibly undefined object.

What you can do is make separate component with user logic:

```js
const Profile = ({user} : {user?: User}) => {
    console.log("Profile log");
    return (
        <Protected user={user}>
            <UserProfile user={user} />
        </Protected>
    )
}
```

or make `Protected` accept [children as a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children):

```js
const Profile = ({ user }: { user?: User }) => {
  console.log('Profile log');
  return (
    <Protected user={user}>
      {() => (
        <>
          <h1>This is Profile</h1>
          <h1>Hello, {user.user_metadata.full_name}!</h1>
          <p> Your email : {user.email}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </Protected>
  );
};
```

`Protected` will roughly look like that:

```js
export function Protected(props) {
  if(!props.user){
    // Make some other redirect logic, you current implementation with object won't work
  }
  // Notice here we calling the children
  return props.children();
}
```